# PyWinAuto, Notepad++ var filename with spaces fails

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a folder with 2 text files, one without and one with spaces in filename:

```
demo\no_spaces.txt
     has spaces.txt
     pwr_npp.py
```

"pwr_npp,py" uses PyWinAuto to automate Notepad++
What it does:

- starts Notepad++ in `-multiInst -nosession` mode
- opens each *.txt file
- sends keys  `CTR+A (select all), CTR+E, CTR+ SHIFT+E, CTR+S (Save) then ALT+F4 (Exit)`

This works OK for filename "`no_spaces.txt`" but fails with "`has spaces.txt`"
With lhe later, Notepad++ displays two MsgBox:

- `'F:\WORK\PyWinAuto\demo\has' doesn't exist. Create it?`
  discarding this one, Notepad++ pops a second MsgBox:
- `'F:\WORK\PyWinAuto\demo\spaces.txt' doesn't exist. Create it?`

The problem seem to be related to the space in the variable 'filename'.
How to deal with this?

@Vasily:

Not from command line, "filename" is provided by a iteration:

```
for filename in glob.glob('F:\WORK\PyWinAuto\demo/*.txt'):
```

Then used after notepad++.exe and cmd line arguments to launch npp:

```
full_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession" + " " +  filename
app = Application(backend="uia").start(full_cmd, timeout=10)
dlg = app.top_window()
# Available key codes to handel Notepad++ 'HTML tag' plugin:
dlg.type_keys('^a')     # select all (Ctrl+A)
etc.
```

If instead of var "filename" I entee a literal like "has spaces.txt" there is no problem - but var "filename" with spaces inside it, like:
filename = "has spaces.txt"
this fails.

Comment: If this script takes file name from command line arguments, each argument must be quoted by `"` or `'`. It's not a Python related question.

Comment: @Vasily, If instead of var "filename" I enter a literal like "has spaces.txt" there is no problem - but var "filename" with spaces inside it, like: filename = "has spaces.txt" this fails.

Comment: Yes, because you need `"\"" + filename + "\""` instead of just `filename`. :) Just try to print `full_cmd`, copy it and execute in `cmd.exe`. You will see the same issue. :)